# Browser plugin to fill in form fields based on the id or name attribute matched against a regular expression?

Tags: web-browser, forms

Is there a browser plugin that will attempt to fill in form fields based on matching the `name` or `id` attribute of a form field matched against a regular expression?

Comment: What site or sites are you trying to use which fail to match for your browser's built-in auto-complete? Are you filling out the same form(s) over and over, or different forms all over the interwebs?

Comment: No I'm developing a form with Google Forms.   Also, I am recalling when I was unemployed a few years ago and what a pain it was to refill all of those form over and over.  An or in a Regex might help in that regard.

Comment: Well, if no better answers are given, you could get a javascript plugin like greasemonkey and write a script to fill form fields out for you and use javascript's regex.